# Jquery Ajax and CORS issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I wrote an AJAX POST request that works:

```
var params = "email=" + email + "&company=" + company + "&subject=" + subject + "&text=" + text;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/submit?" + params, true);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(xhttp.readyState + " " + xhttp.status);
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log("request " + params + " was sent to DB");
        alert("Thank You!");
    }
};
xhttp.send();
```

A colleague recommended working with AJAX JQuery, so I wrote the equivalent function using JQuery:

```
var params = "email=" + email + "&company=" + company + "&subject=" + subject + "&text=" + text;

$.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1/submit',
      type: 'POST',
      data: '{"data":"' + params + '"}' ,
      headers: {
         "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
         "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
         "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
      },
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(data) {
         alert("success");
      },
      error: function(result) {
         alert("error");
      }
   });
```

Unfortunately, this version didn't work and issued a CORS error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/submit. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

However, it's important to note that my server code includes the following line so it should fix CORS problems:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    next();
});
```

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Try adding `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS` in your `res` within `app.use`

Comment: Sending requests to unsecure connections (non `https`) causes CORS error. You can use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) handy chrome extension as a quick work around.

Comment: Also try adding `dataType: "jsonp"` to your ajax request..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, it worked :)

Comment: Great.. Happy coding.. :)